# Regex to match character in order with one or more character repeating consecutively 3 and more times

Tags: regex

For example, I am trying to match the following strings

```
mmmutex
mmuuuTTex
Muuuuuutex
muteeeeeEexxxx
mMutexXxxx
```

....and many similar strings.

They must have `m`, `u`, `t`, `e` and `x` in order with one or more characters repeating consecutively 3 and more times.

I found the following solution

```
^(?i).*([mutex])\\1{2}[mutex]*$
```

but it also matches

```
xxxxxx
mmmmmm
ttttt
eeeee
uuuuuuuuu
```

and many more similar like above which I don't want. See [**this demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/4Fdh3g/1).

Comment: This is probably easier within your programming language of choice - which is ?

Comment: I tried with this: [`(?i)^.*(?=\w*?(.)\1\1)m+u+t+e+x.*`](https://regex101.com/r/jYOcAd/1) (but not sure if this matches your need).

Comment: i am using json as programming language.

Comment: It was not working as supposed to, [see update :)](https://regex101.com/r/aqS6Rh/2)

Comment: @bobblebubble the updated one ^.*(?=\w*?(.)\1\1)m+u+t+e+x+\b.* is working good but also matches comutexxx or similar words like this.

Comment: @ChaCha good catch! for this you'd need to add another word-boundary: [`^.*\b(?=\w*?(.)\1\1)m+u+t+e+x+\b.*`](https://regex101.com/r/n6ZrvC/1) (just noticed, you got it working already)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will do:

```
^(?i).*?(mmm+u+t+e+x+|m+uuu+t+e+x+|m+u+ttt+e+x+|m+u+t+eee+x+|m+u+t+e+xxx+).*$
```

What it does is: it ensure that at least one of the letters is repeating 3 **or** more times.

- `.*?` ensures that the starting `m` characters will enter into the capturing group
- `mmm+u+t+e+x+` at least 3 `m`; or
- `m+uuu+t+e+x+` at least 3 `u`; or
- `m+u+ttt+e+x+` at least 3 `t`; or
- `m+u+t+eee+x+` at least 3 `e`; or
- `m+u+t+e+xxx+` at least 3 `x`
- everything in a parentheses, from the start `^` till the end `$`, but only the `mutex` variations will be in the captured group `\1`.

If your engine does not do case insensitive matching, then you will need this to catch the different cases:

```
^.*?([Mm][Mm][Mm]+[Uu]+[Tt]+[Ee]+[Xx]+|[Mm]+[Uu][Uu][Uu]+[Tt]+[Ee]+[Xx]+|[Mm]+[Uu]+[Tt][Tt][Tt]+[Ee]+[Xx]+|[Mm]+[Uu]+[Tt]+[Ee][Ee][Ee]+[Xx]+|[Mm]+[Uu]+[Tt]+[Ee]+[Xx][Xx][Xx]+).*$
```

Comment: This is a brute force approach, but against 5 characters is a great solution. You could change a triad like `mmm+` to `m{3,}` but that would be less readable. Case insensitive: `[mM]{3,}` could be a good addition...

Comment: True, but I'm trying to use as less as possible features, because not every feature is available everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
(?i)^.*(?=.*(.)\1\1)m+u+t+e+x+.*$
```

How this works:

- `(?i)`: case-insensitive matching
- `^.*`: start of string followed by any char zero or more times
- `(?=`: start of lookahead
- `.*`: any char zero or more times
- `(.)\1\1`: capturing group, capturing any char that is repeated twice
- `)`: end of lookahead
- `m+u+t+e+x+`: `m`, `u`, `t`, and `x`, each occurring one or more times
- `.*$`: any char zero or more times until end of string

Comment: Problem is, that it will match e.g. [`mutex aaa`](https://regex101.com/r/Ip71ON/1) which is probably not wanted. Needs a bit adjustment but I like this idea too.

Answer (score 1):

1. To achieve consecutive matching characters use:

```
mutex
```

2. To catch possible repeating character, use `{1,}` which means one or more, or `{2,3}` which means between two an three repetitions:

```
m{1,}u{1,}t{1,}e{1,}x{1,}
```

Finally:

```
^(?i)m{1,}u{1,}t{1,}e{1,}x{1,}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **@bobble bubble** The following regex resolved my problem.

```
^(?i).*(?=\w*?(.)\1\1)\bm+u+t+e+x+\b.*$
```

check here https://regex101.com/r/p1Nvde/1

Comment: Btw, if you move the first word boundary before the lookahead, you can reduce steps considerably: `^(?i).*\b(?=`...